# colors.xml resource does not work

Tags: java, android, android-xml, android-resources

I created a colors.xml file in my Android app under /res/values/colors.xml.  The contents are...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="Green">#00ff00</color>
</resources>
```

I try to update the background of my a TableRow using...

```
    TableRow test = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.tableRow2);
    test.setBackgroundColor(R.color.Green);
```

This does not set it as green, it is gray instead.  No matter what values I add to the colors.xml file, it is always the same gray color.  However this does work...

```
    TableRow test = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.tableRow2);
    test.setBackgroundColor(android.graphics.Color.GREEN);
```

Is something wrong with my colors.xml?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You should use this instead:

```
TableRow test = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.tableRow2);
test.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Green));
```

Its unfortunate that resource ID and color have same type: `int`. You should get color value from resources via `getColor()` and use that valu as color. While you are using resource ID as color.

Answer (score 4):

Try instead using the command setBackgroundResource, ie

```
TableRow test = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.tableRow2);
test.setBackgroundResource(R.color.Green);
```